# getting flask-recaptcha to work

Tags: python, recaptcha

I have a lot of trouble getting flask-recaptcha to work. I basically follow the tutorial here (https://github.com/mardix/flask-recaptcha), but it just doesn't work. Here is my setup.

In `__iniy__.py` I do

```
from flask import Flask
from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_mail import Message, Mail
from flask.ext.elasticsearch import FlaskElasticsearch
from flask_recaptcha import ReCaptcha

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_pyfile('../config.py')
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
mail = Mail(app)
es = FlaskElasticsearch(app)
recaptcha = ReCaptcha(app=app)

from app import views
```

now I import recaptcha into views.py and setup some config parameters

```
from app import db, app, models, mail, es, recaptcha
app.config.update({
    'RECAPTCHA_ENABLED': True,
    'RECAPTCHA_SITE_KEY': "public",
    'RECAPTCHA_SECRET_KEY': "private"
})
```

and in register.html I include `{{ recaptcha }}`. When the form comes in I check for

```
recaptcha.verify()
```

but that always gives True. The recaptcha is not even shown on the page? 
I have registered my domain under google recaptcha and I use the public and private key provided from that site. 
Instead of using the flask-recaptcha package I can use the snippets provided from the Google recaptcha site and that seems to work fine. 
I would however prefer to use the standard package??
Also how does recaptcha.verify() distinguish between not verified and not submitted (meaning not clicked on)?
any help is appreciated

Progress: Ok I found out that recaptcha is displayed correctly on my website, while under localhost it is not shown at all... I guess this is because localhost is not registered under google recaptcha... very confusing though. Instead one should probably display a message that this domain is not registered... but anyway, I still get

```
recapcha.verify() = True
```

even if I do not click on the recaptcha before submission? Do I have to verify that recaptcha has been submitted?

Answer (score 2):

Just in case somebody has similar trouble - my problem got solved by simply switching the config parameter definition. Setting the config parameters after initializing recaptcha doesn't seem to work. Not sure why. Here is my setup, which works fine:

I don't do anything in `__init__.py` anymore and in `views.py` I have the following code:

```
from flask_recaptcha import ReCaptcha

app.config.update(dict(
    RECAPTCHA_ENABLED = True,
    RECAPTCHA_SITE_KEY = "public",
    RECAPTCHA_SECRET_KEY = "private",
))

recaptcha = ReCaptcha()
recaptcha.init_app(app)
```

And that's it.

Comment: Thanks!! It was same problem for me too. I was setting up properties after initializling and it wasn't showing up.